# Не открывается меню в мобильной версии

Tags: css3, html5

есть сайт в мобильной версии которой не раскрывается менюшка. Тоесть при нажатии на кнопку должен раскрываться список, сама кнопка меню есть но при нажатии ничего не происходит.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Вот сам код

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="header__logo">
              <a href="index.html" class="logo">


                  <img src="images/LOGO.png" style="max-height: 40px;" alt="Logo" > </a>
                
              </div>
              <div class="navbar">
                <div class="yamm">
                  <div class="navbar-header hidden-md hidden-lg hidden-sm">
                    <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-toggle"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
                    <a href="index.html#" class="navbar-brand"></a> </div>
                  <nav id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav">
<li class="first"><a href="" >Главная</a></li>
<li class="first"><a href="#about" class="about">О нас</a></li>
<li class=" dropdown">
<a href="" class="dropdown-toggle nav-down" data-toggle="dropdown"  title="Услуги">
<span   onclick="location.href=''">Услуги<b class="caret"></b></a>
</li>
<li class="last"><a href="#contacts" class="contacts">Контакты</a></li>     
                    </ul>
                  </nav>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: bootstrap?????? Проверь, всё ли подключено верно, скрипты\линки

Comment: Пожмякайте по этим ссылкам, и проверьте все ли а вас верно подключено. Подключение - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/ . Сам `Navbar` - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/. В зависимости от подключенной у вас версии выберите там нужную.

Comment: Заработало после того как я поочередно подключил скрипты. Спасибо помогло